# Updating Multi Value Drop Down fields in Rally using Ruby

Tags: ruby, rally

I have a large collection of test cases in Rally. To make it easier to search for test cases I have introduced a new field to the test case object, called "Functionality". This field has Attribute Type "Drop Down List (Multi Value)". Now I need to create a Ruby script so I can assign (potentially multiple) values to this field and this is where my question comes: How do I code that? I would assume the variable holds an array or a pointer to a list. I would want to be able to assign and delete individual values without affecting the other values that was already assigned to a particular test case.

From looking at what Rally returns when I query on the variable, I don't really get any idea of how it is structured.

```
    "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/attributedefinition/68878414616", "_refObjectUUID": "8cb97bae-ea25-4805-8e5b-77944ddc4f6a", "_refObjectName": "Functionality", "_type": "AttributeDefinition"}, "StringValue": "Account History", "ValueIndex": 0, "_type": "AllowedAttributeValue"}, {"_rallyAPIMajor": "2", "_rallyAPIMinor": "0", "_ref":
```

Have looked through examples and the Rally API, but have not been able to find any information on how this is done.

UPDATE:
Based on the code snippet from @JPKole, I created a program.

```
   fields = {:attributedefinition => { '_ref' => this_artifact._ref },
             :stringvalue         => string_value
   }
   puts fields
   puts "Allowed Attribute Value is #{:allowedattributevalue}"
   new_value = @rally.create(:allowedattributevalue, fields)
```

I think the program loads the right values into the string_value and the fields variable. The puts lines gives: 
Processing Test Case TC7203

{:attributedefinition=>{"_ref"=>"https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/testcase/71703906048"}, :stringvalue=>"Promotion"}
Allowed Attribute Value is allowedattributevalue

where 71703906048 is the ID of the test case I'm working on.
But then I get the following:

Test Case TC7203 not updated due to error

Error on request - https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/allowedattributevalue/create?workspace=workspace/50775741420 -
{:errors=>["**We\u02BCre sorry!  An unexpected error has occurred.**
We have recorded this error and will begin to investigate it.  In the mean
e, if you would like to speak with our Support Team, please reference the information below:
<
/>com.rallydev.util.UnableToInvokeMethodException: Method AllowedAttributeValue.newAllowedAttributeValue(TestCase) does not exist
2016-11-14 01:37
 CST America/Chicago"], :warnings=>[]}
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rally_api-1.2.1/lib/rally_api/rally_json_connection.rb:154:in `send_request'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rally_api-1.2.1/lib/rally_api/rally_rest_json.rb:107:in`send_request'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rally_api-1.2.1/lib/rally_api/rally_rest_json.rb:189:in `create'
C:/Ruby22-x64/Sorens Ruby/UpdateFunct1.rb:118:in`block (2 levels) in '
C:/Ruby22-x64/Sorens Ruby/UpdateFunct1.rb:103:in `each'
C:/Ruby22-x64/Sorens Ruby/UpdateFunct1.rb:103:in`block in '
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rally_api-1.2.1/lib/rally_api/rally_query_result.rb:22:in `block in each'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rally_api-1.2.1/lib/rally_api/rally_query_result.rb:21:in`each'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rally_api-1.2.1/lib/rally_api/rally_query_result.rb:21:in `each'
C:/Ruby22-x64/Sorens Ruby/UpdateFunct1.rb:97:in`'

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The documentation (https://help.rallydev.com/create-custom-fields#create ) on 2016-11-01 says "Multi-value custom fields are not available for Web Services API queries. All other custom fields are available for queries."

Comment: That documentation was valid in the past, but MVCF's are fully usable through WSAPI now.  Thanks for pointing this out- we've removed that bullet in the help so it is now more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

"value_strings" is an array of new values;
"current_allowed_values" is an array of existing values:

```
 ....
 value_strings.each do |string_value|
   string_value.strip!
   if current_allowed_values.include?(string_value)
     puts "Skipping #{string_value} (already exists)"
   else
     puts "  Adding value: #{string_value}"
     fields = {:attributedefinition => { '_ref' => attribute._ref },
               :stringvalue         => string_value
     }
     new_value = @rally.create(:allowedattributevalue, fields)
   end
 end
```

Comment: Note: I've never been able to figure out how to delete a value.

Comment: You should be able to delete an allowedattributevalue from a MVCF attributedefinition the same as you would any other object.  I think @JPKole is referring to some other types of field values which currently cannot be deleted via wsapi...